# jquery get ID from hash in URL to .load() div content

Tags: jquery, hash

I have my page so far: `einserpasch.com`

The crucial markup is this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#content_01" id="content_01"> !?! </a></li>
</ul>
```

And the `div`-container at the end of the document:

```
<div id="haupt_iframe">
</div>
```

On clicking on the drop down menu items the jQuery function loads content from a HTML file into the div container (I omitted the fading in the code below) while the URL in my browser gains the `#`-tag ending (like `einserpasch.com/#content_01`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li a").click(function(){ 
    var knopf = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#haupt_iframe").load("bilder/"+knopf+".html");               
});
```

So far no problem.
but now I want a direct link to the different galleries. To make the images show in the div container only by typing in the correct URL including the `#`-sign.
the idea was that having an hash sign in the URL would make me get an id selector when i read it with `window.location.hash`.
I tried to manage it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  if(window.location.hash){
  $(window.location.hash).trigger(function(){
    var knopf = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#haupt_iframe").load("bilder/"+knopf+".html");
  });
  };
});
```

But so far, only the click on the `a` attribute fires the function but not typing in the URL with the specific `#`-tag at the end. like `einserpasch.com/#painting`.

So what am I missing to make me have a direct link?

Thanks in advance!
clemens :)

ps.: yes, i posted this in code review because i wanted you to review my code. but as a part of my code doesn't work the post was closed. i'm still learning the rules of this community...

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding for your question is correct, you can change your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  if(window.location.hash){
    var knopf = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    $("#haupt_iframe").load("bilder/" + knopf + ".html");
  };
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: i would love to do so but i don't have enough reputation to vote for your answer ;)